# Issue setting ng-grid data with drop down default

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is a simplified version of what I have. I have two tables: FoodType and Food. FoodType has Beverages and Deserts in it. The columns are Id and Name. Food has Coke, Sprite, Root beer, pie, cake and ice cream. The columns in this table are Id, Name and FoodTypeId (FK).

On my page I have a drop down for the FoodType and a grid for the Food. When the user selects a FoodType the associated Food is displayed in the ng-grid. This works.

The user logs in and has their default food type id associated with their user name. When the page loads though, the default food type displays in for the drop down but all the food displays in the grid. And I can't see why. Can anyone see?

```
<select ng-model="vm.selectedFoodType"
                        ng-options="foodType.Id as foodType.Name for foodType in vm.foodType"
                        ng-change="vm.foodGridOptions.filterOptions.filterText = vm.selectedFoodType ? 'FoodTypeId:' + vm.selectedFoodType : ''"
                        class="form-control">
                    <option value="">- Select Food Type -</option>
                </select>
```

```
function getFood() {
        return datacontext.getFood()
            .then(function (response) {
                return vm.food = response.data;
            })
            .catch(function (exception) {
                logError('Call to Get Food Failed.' + exception.data.ExceptionMessage, null, true)
            });
    }


function getFoodType() {
        return datacontext.getFoodType()
            .then(function (response) { return vm.foodType = response.data; })
            .catch(function (exception) { logError('Call to Get Food Type  Failed: ' + exception.data.ExceptionMessage, null, true) });
    }


vm.foodGridOptions = {
        data: 'vm.food',
        enableRowSelection: true,
        multiSelect: false,
        columnDefs: [
            { field: 'FoodTypeId', displayName: 'FoodTypeId', visible: false },
            { field: 'Name', displayName: 'Food', minWidth: 250, width: 'auto', resizable: true },

        ],
        filterOptions: { filterText: vm.selectedFoodType, useExternalFilter: false },
        sortInfo: { fields: ['vm.food.Name'], directions: ['asc'] },
        afterSelectionChange: function (rowItem) {
            if (!rowItem.selected)
                return;

            vm.importLog = rowItem.entity;
            vm.appyDisabled = false;

        }
    };
 function getDefaultFoodType() {
        return datacontext.getUser(user.username)
            .then(function (response) {
                vm.selectedFoodType = response.data.DefaultFoodTypeId;
            });
    }
```

Comment: I added two console.log functions in the code: one just after the vm.foodGridOptions and one in getDefaultFoodType. Both are writing the value of the vm.selectedFoodType to the console. The first one is "undefined" and the second one has a value. I'm not sure how to assign vm.selectedFoodType AFTER it actually has been set.